# warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10625]

Tags: .net

The foreign key property 'Group.TeacherId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'TeacherId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

I deleted from the first postgreSQL. Then I said that I will correct it by migrating from Visual Studio. It's not happening somehow. As I said, I deleted the unnecessary CourseId and TeacherId1 columns from the first postgreSQL. Then I did a migration, and an empty migration came back. Then I typed dotnet ef database update --startup-project ..\Zeemlin.Api. Then when I look in migration, it is empty. I manually entered information and updated again. But for some reason it is returning this error again

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.